The argument type 'StateNotifierProvider<MainPageDataController, MainPageData>'
hello i am implementing an app in flutter and while doing so i am stuck at a place in the following line
_mainPageDataController = ref.watch(MainPageDataControllerProvider);
_mainPageData = ref.watch(MainPageDataControllerProvider.state);
i have to implement these lines , however the IDE is showing error as
The argument type 'StateNotifierProvider<MainPageDataController, MainPageData>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderListenable'.
and
The getter 'state' isn't defined for the type 'StateNotifierProvider<MainPageDataController, MainPageData>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'state', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'state'.
Please help me out!!
i went according to the quick fixes shown by Vs code however then it says State Error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
